# Nginx patch request ends up with Invalid CORS request

Tags: nginx, javascript, cors, springboot

It's simple set up.

Three docker containers in same network.

1. ReactJs - production build on nginx server
2. Spring Boot
3. Mysql

GET, POST request works like a charm but when i try to use PATCH request i ends up with

**Invalid CORS request**

```
2021/09/01 23:17:27 [notice] 31#31: *5 "/api/(.*)" matches "/api/task/assign/5/S01", client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "PATCH /api/task/assign/5/S01 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/operator/controlpanel"
2021/09/01 23:17:27 [notice] 31#31: *5 rewritten data: "/task/assign/5/S01", args: "", client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "PATCH /api/task/assign/5/S01 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/operator/controlpanel"
172.18.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2021:23:17:27 +0000] "PATCH /api/task/assign/5/S01 HTTP/1.1" 403 31 "http://localhost/operator/controlpanel" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT xx; Win64; x64; rv:xx) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0" "-"
```

My nginx configuration

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     localhost;
  expires -1;
  etag off;
  proxy_no_cache 1;
  rewrite_log on;

 location / {
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   try_files $uri /index.html;
 }

  location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_pass http://app:8080;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        default_type  application/json;
  }
}
```

On spring boot end i do not received any request info so i assume it has been blocked before sending it to spring server.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check your application's log.

Comment: @MichaelHampton
Like i mentioned "On spring boot end i do not received any request info so i assume it has been blocked before sending it to spring server." Plus PATCH, PUT, DELETE works fine without nginx

Comment: Your app sent a 403 Forbidden error, so it must be doing something. Make sure your app is actually logging.

Comment: @Lucas, Encountering the same error here, did you ever find a solution? We can access the site without the proxy with no problems. As soon as the proxy is introduced, PATCH method results in 403 with a response of "Invalid CORS Request"

Comment: @Slicktrick afair Michael was 100% correct spring didn't log that denial of access. Try to debug it before cors check.

Comment: @Lucas thanks for getting back to me. In my case it turned out to be a configuration issue on the end server the proxy was pointed to. Sounds like a similar situation to yours, but the odd part was that an Apache proxy server worked just fine. For whatever reason the Nginx proxy was blocked for just the PATCH request. Made me think it had to be Nginx, but that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your app sent a 403 Forbidden error, so it must be doing something. Make sure your app is actually logging. – 
> Michael Hampton
> Sep 2, 2021 at 16:13

For some reason spring didn't put that in logs.
If someone face same problem try to debug request before cors filter.